Convert or Revert?
Which of the following nouns "convert/revert" is more accurate to describe someone who left his religion and accepted a new one?

From the point of view of the religion that is being left, the word is "apostate"

someone who has given up their religion or left a political party

A "convert" is someone who has joined a religion. A "revert" is someone who returns to a religion they left previously.

So a Christian who leaves Christianity and accepts Hinduism; for example,  is called a convert. Right?

It should be noted that the common term within Islam for one who converts to Islam is "revert", because Islam holds that all are born as "natural" Moslems, and are led astray into other religions, so "converting" to Islam is really "reverting" to their natural religion. In the general case, however, the above is correct.

I was a bit surprised to see that noun "revert" explicitly has that specific sense in the full OED. But it goes back to 1597, so I suppose things were a bit different then. I don't see any terms to distinguish "convert" = someone who has joined a religion from someone who either did or didn't have a religion before converting. Are there any such terms?

M-W uses cyclical definitions (a convert ... to convert ... conversion) which don't really help here. CD's definition is very hypernymic. But Britannica has a more specific definition than the one you suggest: << convert  [noun]: a person who has changed to a different religion'. >>

@MoAli Largely  incidentally. A convert speaks only to the new condition. It says nothing about the old condition apart from the fact that the new and old conditions differ from each other. Thus anyone who becomes a "something" is a "something" convert. It doesn't matter what they were before they were a "something". So you do not have to "leave" anything. You don't have to be religious at all!
